# Is yield* equivalent to a while loop with plain yield in javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I have a line like:

```
yield* foo()
```

Could I replace it with something to the tune of:

```
while(true) {
   var x = foo.next();
   if(x.done)
       break;
    yield x;
}
```

Clearly that's more verbose, but I'm trying to understand if yield* is merely syntactic sugar, or if there's some semantic aspect I'm unclear on.

Comment: Nope, it's pretty much that. Simpler: `for (var x of foo()) { yield x; }`. Spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-generator-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation . *edit:* Well, you have to *call* `foo()` first to get the iterator.

Comment: _"The `yield*` expression is used to delegate to another generator or iterable object."_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*

Comment: Thanks, @FelixKling. I feel myself developing cancer of the semicolon.

Comment: And thanks for the spec link, @FelixKling. The specification has some extra features for handling throws from iterables. And there's an oddity in that yield actually yields an IterResultObject that yield* does not.... plus something else about a type called "return".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `yield x` you need to do `yield x.value`. You also need to call `foo` to get the iterator. `.next` is a method of the iterator returned by the `foo` generator.

```js
function *foo() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}

function *f() {
  yield *foo();
}

console.log(Array.from(f()));

function *g() {
  var iterator = foo();
  while (true) {
    var x = iterator.next();
    if (x.done) break;
    yield x.value;
  }
}

console.log(Array.from(g()));
```